# How to assign four threads to four methods from different files? (multithreaded java socket programming)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to create a text messaging program with three files (main function file, client file, server file) where text messages can be sent and received at the same time, multiple times (ability to send multiple messages by pressing enter after each message, ability to receive multiple messages after connection after the other side presses enter after each message)

There are four threads (one thread for receiving messages on server, one thread for sending messages on server, one thread for receiving messages on client, one thread for sending messages on client)

If "-l" is present on the command line, it will run as a server, otherwise it will run as a client

Command line arguments to run server:

```
java DirectMessengerCombined -l 3000
```

Command line arguments to run client:

```
java DirectMessengerCombined 3000
```

The command line arguments (String[] args) should be accessible to all 3 files.

Here is the code where the threads are created:

Code of main function file:

```
 import java.io.IOException;


public class DirectMessengerCombined implements Runnable
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        DirectMessengerClient client1 = null;
        DirectMessengerServer server1 = null;
        Thread ServerRead = new Thread ();
        Thread ServerWrite = new Thread ();
        Thread ClientRead = new Thread ();
        Thread ClientWrite = new Thread ();
          for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
          {

              if (args.length == 1) 
              {
                 client1  = new DirectMessengerClient(args);
                 client1.ClientRun(args);
                 ClientRead.start();
                 ClientWrite.start();


              }
              else if (args.length == 2)
              {
                 server1 = new DirectMessengerServer(args);
                 server1.ServerRun(args);
                 ServerRead.start();
                 ServerWrite.start();

              }
           i=args.length + 20;
          } 
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //This method is just to get rid of the "implements" error
        //There are four threads, so which one is accessing this method??
    }

}
```

In the following code there are comments such as "//I would like this to be the ServerRead thread method". I would like to know how to make that comment viable or put it into real code somehow to make it work with the corresponding threads in the main function file

Code of Server file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.IIOException;


public class DirectMessengerServer implements Runnable
{

    private String[] serverArgs; 
    private static Socket socket;
    public boolean keepRunning = true;
    int ConnectOnce = 0;

    public DirectMessengerServer(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // set the instance variable
        this.serverArgs = args;
        run();
    }

      public String[] ServerRun(String[] args) throws IOException 
      {

        serverArgs = args;
        serverArgs = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);

        return serverArgs;

      }



//I would like this to be the ServerRead thread method 
public void run() 
{  


    try
    {
        if(ConnectOnce == 0)
        {
            int port_number1 = Integer.valueOf(serverArgs[1]);
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
            socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
            ConnectOnce = 4;
        }
        while(keepRunning)
        {

            //Reading the message from the client

//BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String MessageFromClient = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from client: "+ MessageFromClient);

           // ServerSend.start();

            runSend();



        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}

//I would like this to be the ServerWrite thread method 
public void runSend()
{   
    while(keepRunning)
    {
        System.out.println("Server sending thread is now running");
        try
        {         

            //Send the message to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            //creating message to send from standard input
            String newmessage = "";
            try 
            {
                // input the message from standard input
                BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader( 
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String line = "";

                line= input.readLine(); 
                    newmessage += line + " ";

            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
            }
            String sendMessage = newmessage;
            bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to client: "+sendMessage);
            ConnectOnce = 4;
           // run();
        }


        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}


}
```

Client file code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class DirectMessengerClient
{
    private String[] clientArgs;
    private static Socket socket;
    public boolean keepRunning = true;
    public DirectMessengerClient(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // set the instance variable
        this.clientArgs = args;
        run(args);


    }
    public String[] ClientRun(String[] args)
    {
        clientArgs = args;
        clientArgs = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);
        return clientArgs;
    }

  //I would like this to be the ServerWrite thread method 
    public void run(String args[]) throws IOException
    {   
        System.out.println("Client send thread is now running");
        while(keepRunning)
        {             
             String port_number1= args[0];
             System.out.println("Port number is: " + port_number1);
             int port = Integer.valueOf(port_number1);
             String host = "localhost";
             InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
             socket = new Socket(address, port);


             //Send the message to the server
             OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
             OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

             //creating message to send from standard input
             String newmessage = "";
             try 
             {
                 // input the message from standard input
                 BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                 String line = "";

                 line= input.readLine(); 
                 newmessage += line + " ";


              }
              catch ( Exception e )
              {
                     System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
              }
                String sendMessage = newmessage;
                bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
                bw.flush();
                System.out.println("Message sent to server: "+sendMessage);
                runClientRead(args);
            }

        }


  //I would like this to be the ClientRead thread method 
    public void runClientRead(String args[]) throws IOException
    {   
        System.out.println("Client recieve/read thread is now running");

            //Integer port= Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
            //String host = "localhost";
            //InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            //socket = new Socket(address, port);

            //Get the return message from the server
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String MessageFromServer = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from server: " + MessageFromServer);

    }
}
```

My question is how to make those methods work with the threads inside the main function file and/or how to turn the comments into real code for the corresponding threads in the main file?

EDIT: I am able to get it to send one message at a time successfully now, is there a way to make it so I can send and receive multiple messages at a time?

Comment: I think you want something like `Thread serverRead = new Thread (new DirectMessengerServer(args));` to create the thread. Then `serverRead.start();` to start it. You definitely don't want to call `run` from the constructor.

Comment: Creating the client and server in the same JVM seems a bit odd.

Comment: @bradimus I see. Both of the lines: `Thread serverRead = new Thread (new DirectMessengerServer(args));` and the `serverRead.Start();` are located in the main function file correct? Or should the lines be located inside the server file?